# Django. Intermediate page after authentication

Tags: django, django-admin, django-urls, django-authentication

I wrote middleware that process requests from admin log in page. How can I redirect user after authentication to some intermediate page with some 'Continue' button and this button will redirect me to page which should be showed in standard scenario.

I set my middleware after AuthenticationMiddleware in settings list. Despite of this if I set some return statement in my middleware, user authentication process fails.

I need this to show some additional info about authentication results on some Atlassian services. Don't want to do it via JavaScript so decided to implement intermediate page functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a middleware, create a template with that auth information and use the function render_to_response at the end of your login view to render that template. You can add variables to this function to give extra information.

Example:

```
return render_to_response('my_template.html',
                      my_data_dictionary,
                      context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: Should I override default django admin login for this?

Comment: @sunprophit just create a view for login and call django admin login inside if it, this way you are using django admin and you select the next template to render.

Comment: Still didn't get it how can I interfere in django admin login process. As I understand django log in logic is placed in some default middleware and login view is calling from this middleware(RemoteUserMiddleware if I understanding it right). Where should I inject my view function in this case?

Comment: So this view should be specified in my urls.py? But in admin app I want to redirect to login form from every page which unauthorized user can't see. It is like admin app works now.

Comment: (r'^login/$', 'your_app.views.login'),

Comment: login - I don't have this in any of my url. It is not my decision - it is how django admin works. There is no need to specify some_site/login to see login form. Django checks if view need authorization and if user is unauthorized. And if user needs authorization RemoteUserMiddleware doing work to show user login page. And there is no any login in urls need. Am I wrong?